# Shaders casting uint8 to float, and reinterpretting it back to uint

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a vertex attribute that's being chewed up very weird by my shaders.  It's uploaded to the VBO as a `(uint8)1` but when the fragment shader sees it, it's interpreted as a `10653532160`, or `0x3F800000` which some of you might recognize as being the bit pattern for a `1.0f` in floating point.

I have no ideas as to why?  I can confirm that it is uploaded to the VBO as a 1 (`0x00000001`) though.

The vertex attribute is defined as:

```
struct Vertex{
    ...
    glm::u8vec4 c2; // attribute with problems
};
// not-normalized
glVertexAttribPointer(aColor2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, c2));
```

While the shader has that attribute bound with

```
glBindAttribLocation(programID, aColor2, "c2");
```

The vertex shader passes along the attribute pretty uneventfully:

```
#version 330
in lowp uvec4 c2; // <-- this value is uploaded to the VBO as 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01;
flat out lowp uvec4 indices;

void main(){
    indices = c2;
}
```

And finally the fragment shader gets ahold of it:

```
flat in lowp uvec4 indices; // <-- this value is now 0, 0, 0, 0x3F800000
out lowp vec4 fragColor;
void main(){
    fragColor = vec4(indices) / 256.0;
}
```

The `indices` varying leaves the vertex shader as a `0x3F800000` for `indices.w` according to my shader inspector, so something odd is happening there?  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the type of an vertex attribute is integral, then you have to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` rather than `glVertexAttribPointer` (focus on `I`). See [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml).

The type which is specified in `glVertexAttribPointer` is the type of the data in source buffer and doesn't specify the target attribute type in the shader. If you use `glVertexAttribPointer`, then the type of the attribute in the shader program is assumed to be floating point, and the integral data are converted.
If you use `glVertexAttribIPointer` then the values left as integer values.

Comment: oh That Is ****ed... I would've never suspected that in 100 years, thank you

Comment: @AnneQuinn I had the same issue the first time I use an integral attribute. You're welcome.